# How to make every message process successfully?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, message-queue

Below is a service with set of 3 Go-routines that process a message from Kafka:

[image]

---

Channel-1 & Channel-2 are unbuffered data channels in Go. Channel is like a queuing mechanism.

Goroutine-1 reads a message from a kafka topic, throw its message payload on Channel-1, after validation of the message.

Goroutine-2 reads from Channel-1 and processes the payload and throws the processed payload on Channel-2.

Goroutine-3 reads from Channel-2 and encapsulates the processed payload into http packet and perform http requests(using http client) to another service.

Loophole in the above flow: In our case, processing fails either  due to bad network connections between services or remote service is not ready to accept http requests from Go-routine3(http client timeout), due to which, above service lose that message(already read from Kafka topic).

---

Goroutine-1 currently subscribes the message from Kafka **without** an acknowledgement sent to Kafka(to inform that specific message is processed successfully by Goroutine-3)

Correctness is preferred over performance.

---

How to ensure that every message is processed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g., add a feedback from Goroutine-3 to Goroutine-1 through new Channel-3. Goroutine-1 will block until it get acknowledgement from Channel-3.

```
// in gorouting 1
channel1 <- data
select {
    case <-channel3:
    case <-ctx.Done(): // or smth else to prevent deadlock 
}
...
// in gorouting 3
data := <-channel2
for {
    if err := sendData(data); err == nil {
        break
    }
}
channel3<-struct{}{}
```

Comment: Yes, I was preferring feedback approach

Comment: But just wondering, how the closing principle(of channels) apply, during shutdown of service? As per the closing principle, Goroutine3 should close channel3

Comment: It depends on realisation. In goroutine 3 you can select from two channels: channel2  to process data and shutdown channel (e.g. ctx.Done()) to close channel3 and return

Comment: I see a glitch in feedback approach:  I cannot scale this to  multiple pipelines(where each pipeline is Goroutine-1, Goroutine-2 & Go-routine-3 shown above), because if one pipeline send negative acknowledgement, then all the messages from that message is again re-processed

Comment: Goroutine won't send acknowledgment until it successfully performs its job. If it is needed a kind of "negative" acknowledgment, that negative ack should be processed depending of superior logic: e.g., can such messages be deferred to process, or do they have to be processed in order, or can they be discarded after some number of unsuccessful tries, or smth else

Answer (score 1):

To ensuring correctness you need to commit (=acknowledge) the message after processing finished successfully.
For the cases when the processing wasn't finished successfully - in general, you need to implement retry mechanism by yourself.
That should be specific to your use-case, but generally you throw the message back to a dedicated Kafka retry topic (that you create), add a sleep and process the message again. if after x times the processing fails - you throw the message to a DLQ (=dead letter queue).
You can read more here:
https://eng.uber.com/reliable-reprocessing/
https://www.confluent.io/blog/error-handling-patterns-in-kafka/

Comment: Instead of retry, If the processing wasn't finished successfully, then we commit(=ack) to kafka as  `false` instead of `true`, so that the message is again consumed from kafka.

Comment: @overexchange in that way you're exposed to a deadlock, I think that you need to stop after x times, that could be achieved with a retry mechanism.